# Retrofit 2.0 + Dagger 2.0 multiple dispatchers

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit2, dagger-2

I currently have a `Retrofit` client class to make network calls. The same client is used for unit testing as well. What i want is to keep using the same class but if unit testing the app simply switch the `Dispatcher` so as to execute all of the network calls synchronously and monitor the results.

The easiest way around that would be to simply create a couple of provide methods like below for the `Dispatcher` using `Dagger 2.0`:

```
@Provides
@Named("RealDispatcher")
@Singleton
public Dispatcher provideDispatcher() {
    dispatcher =  new Dispatcher();
    return dispatcher;
}

@Provides
@Named("TestDispatcher")
@Singleton
public Dispatcher provideTestDispatcher() {
    dispatcher =  new Dispatcher(newSynchronousExecutorService());
    return dispatcher;
}
```

The component class:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RetrofitModule.class})
public interface RetrofitComponent {

    void inject(RestClient restClient);
}
```

The conundrum being, how do i dynamically switch the `Dispatcher` based on if its in the "default" mode or "unit testing" mode. Since the type association in `Dagger 2.0` for injection is a strong one, how can i keep changing it around.

`Retrofit` client setup:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static ApiCall REST_CLIENT;
    @Inject
    @Named("RealDispatcher")
    static Dispatcher dispatcher; ---> need to switch this dynamically

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        retrofitComponent.inject(this);
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.setDispatcher(dispatcher); ---->add dispatcher based on "default" or "unit testing" mode.
        httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MainActivity.URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(ApiCall.class);
    }

}
```